# React Native App with implemented Carplay doesnt show content on carplay screen if IPhone App is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, carplay

Apps like Spotify, Tidal etc show content if the phone apps are terminated and i click on the App Icon in Carplay Simulator. My App doesnt so, it shows an empty screen. If the phone app is in background or active, everything is working well. I have no idea what i am doing wrong. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Some code:

```
import Foundation
import CarPlay
class SceneDelegateCarPlay: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
...
func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    print("SceneDelegateCarPlay.templateApplicationScene(), didConnect")
    // start render content
    ...
}
```

"templateApplicationScene is called and render content when:

1. Carplay App is closed & Iphone App is active or in background -> Click on Carplay App Icon
2. Carplay App is open (no content visible) & Iphone App is terminated -> Start Iphone App

I wonder how i can render content outside of a case like these